# Detect file deletion while using a FileOutputStream

Tags: java, unix, fileoutputstream

I have created a Java process which writes to a plain text file and another Java process which consumes this text file. The 'consumer' reads then deletes the text file. For the sake of simplicity, I do not use file locks (I know it may lead to concurrency problems).

The 'consumer' process runs every 30 minutes from `crontab`. The 'producer' process currently just redirects whatever it receives from the standard input to the text file. This is just for testing - in the future, the 'producer' process will write the text file by itself.

The 'producer' process opens a `FileOutputStream` once and keeps writing to the text file usign this output stream. The problem is when the 'consumer' deletes the file. Since I'm in an UNIX environment, this situation is handled 'gracefully': the 'producer' keeps working as if nothing happened, since the `inode` of the file is still valid, but the file can no longer be found in the file system. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989069/6242158) provides a way to handle this situation using C. Since I'm using Java, which is portable and therefore hides all platform-specific features, I'm not able to use the solution presented there.

Is there a portable way in Java to detect when the file was deleted while the `FileOutputStream` was still open?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a robust way for your processes to communicate, and the best I can advise is to stop doing that.

As far as I know there isn't a reliable way for a C program to detect when a file being written is unlinked, let alone a Java program. (The [accepted answer you've linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989069/7512) can only poll the directory entry to see if it's still there; I don't consider this sufficiently robust).

As you've noticed, UNIX doesn't consider it abnormal for an open file to be unlinked (indeed, it's an established practice to create a named tempfile, grab a filehandle, then delete it from the directory so that other processes can't get at it, before reading and writing).

If you must use files, consider having your consumer poll a directory. Have a `.../pending/` directory for files in the process of being written and `.../inbox/` for files that are ready for processing.

- Producer creates a new uniquefilename (e.g. a UUID) and writes a new file to `pending/`.
- After closing the file, Producer moves the file to `inbox/` -- as long as both dirs are on the same filesystem, this will just be a relink, so the file will never be incomplete in `inbox/`.
- Consumer looks for files in `inbox/`, reads them and deletes when done.

You can enhance this with more directories if there are eventually multiple consumers, but there's no immediate need.

But polling files/directories is always a bit fragile. Consider a database or a message queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the filename itself for existence:

```
if (!Files.exists(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))) {
    // The consumer has deleted the file.
}
```

but in any case, shouldn't the consumer be *waiting* for the producer to finish writing the file before it reads & deletes it? If it did, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: You are correct, it would make more sense to lock the file. My situation is similar to that of `logrotate`. It creates the compressed file and deletes the log file even if the 'logger' is still writing logs.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this the way you're intending to do, you might have to look at JNI, which lets you call c/c++ functions from within Java, but this might also require you to program a wrapper-library for stat/fstat first (in c/c++).

However - that will cause you major headache.

This might be a workaround which doesnt require much change to your code right now (i assume).
You can let the producer write to a new File each time its producing new Data. Depending on the amount, you might want to group the data, so that the directory wont be flooded with files. For example, one file per minute that contains all data that's been produced so far.
Also it might be a good idea to write the files to another directory first and then move them to your Consumers input-directory - i'm a bit paranoid here, because there could be some race-conditions causing you some dataloss... - moving the files after everything has been already written and then moving them will make sure, no data gets lost.

Hope this helps Good luck :)